# Prove $S_{2n}\leq\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin \lambda x}{\sin x}d x\leq S_{2n-1}$ where $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}$

Tags: integration, inequality, fourier-analysis

> Suppose $n\in \mathbb{N}_+$, $4n-2\leqslant\lambda \leqslant 4n$. How to prove $$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}\leqslant\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin \lambda x}{\sin x}dx\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}\ ?$$

We know that forall $x\in (0,\pi)$,

\begin{align*}
\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}\sin(2k-1)x=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^x\frac{\sin 2nt}{\sin t} dt,
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}\sin(2k-1)x=\frac12\int_0^x\frac{\sin 2nt}{\sin t} dt.
\end{align*}
Place $x=\pi/2$, and replace $n$ by $2n,2n-1$ respectively, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}=&\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin 4nt}{\sin t} dt,\\
\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}=&\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin (4n-2)t}{\sin t} dt.
\end{align*}

I wonder why it choose $\lambda\in [4n-2,4n]$. I have tried to prove that
$$f(\lambda)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin \lambda x}{\sin x}d x$$
is decreasing, but without any result.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've obtained $f(4n-2)=2S_{2n-1}$ and $f(4n)=2S_{2n}$, the conjecture you're trying to prove would rather be $2S_{2n}\leqslant f(\lambda)\leqslant 2S_{2n-1}$ for $4n-2\leqslant\lambda\leqslant 4n$. **But it doesn't hold.** The minima $\lambda_n\in[4n-2,4n]$ of $f(\lambda)$ are slightly less than $4n$ for $1\leqslant n\leqslant 5$ (at least):
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|}
n&\lambda_n&f(\lambda_n)&f(4n)\\\hline
1&3.9063687163-&1.3307753943-&1.3333333333+\\
2&7.9505549212+&1.4472480295+&1.4476190476+\\
3&11.966609219-&1.4879093073-&1.4880230880+\\
4&15.974835197-&1.5084872853-&1.5085359085+\\
5&19.979821495+&1.5208947612+&1.5209198095-\\
\hline\end{array}$$
[An interesting question would be the asymptotics of $4n-\lambda_n$...]

Comment: Thanks !A skeptical attitude toward things is what I have learned.Maybe we have to assume that $\lambda $ is an integer.then when $\lambda=4n-1$,the integral is $\frac{\pi}4$,and the conclusion holds.